# How do I have SWIG a treat a return value of const char* as binary data (for Python)?

Tags: python, swig, swig-typemap

I have a function that takes a parameter (a size) that will dictate how large the byte array that is returned will be. The byte array is returned as a `const char*`. I want to use this from Python and get a byte string as the return value.

```
const char* getName( int arg1, int arg2, size_t byteCount );
```

I could, perhaps, define an `out` typemap, like:

```
%typemap(out) const char* const {
    $result = PyBytes_FromStringAndSize($1,<how_can_I_get_the_input_param?>);
}
```

but this would change *all* functions that return `const char*`, including ones that are returning normal NULL-terminated C strings.

Also, how can I access one of the (input) function parameters within an `out` typemap?

Comment: This is just a re-wording of your previous question, which I just answered.  It answers this as well.  Closing as a duplicate.  Suggest editing the other answer with this information/re-titling.

Comment: The real-world problem is the same, but the questions are distinct. In that question, I wanted to know how (or whether it was possible) to apply a typemap to a specific function (by name). This question is about how to get a byte string from a function returning a char pointer. The answer you provided probably belongs here rather than there.